# spring data jpa null parameter to native query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

exception details - **Caused by : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: exptected NUMBER got BINARY**

```java
public interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository {

    public static final FINDSQL = " select a, b, c from exp_attr ea, dep_attr da  where ea.id = da.id AND ea.sysId = :sysId";

    @Query(value = FINDSQL , nativeQuery=true)
    List<ProjectionInterface> getExampleDetails(@Param("sysId") Integer sysId);
}
```

```java
public class RestApi {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleRepository exampleRepository;

    public String testJpaRepo(){
        Integer sysId = 123;
        exampleRepository.getExampleDetails(sysId);
    }
}
```

```java
public interface ProjectionInterface {
 
 Integer getA();

 String getB();

 String getC();

}
```

When I am passing sysId = 123, it works fine, but when sysId is null then it gives following exception

**Caused by : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: exptected NUMBER got BINARY**

Comment: And you want to return all rows when `sysId` is null ? If yes you have to use `AND (:sysId IS NULL OR ea.sysId = :sysId)` as you cannot perform any comparison on NULL values by using `=` operator.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. My expectation is query execution should not break when sysId is null.  It throws an exception. If sysId is null it should return empty list.  I tried this **AND (:sysId IS NULL OR ea.sysId = :sysId** but gives same exception.